# How can I run a C# form application within a Flutter project?

Tags: c#, windows, flutter

I moved my C# form project into my Flutter project. I run my C# application with process.run. It works in VS Code, but when I build it for Windows, process.run works but the window closes without being visible. How can I run the exe in my project?

**this my code**:

```
  void writeFilesPath(String path) async {
try {
  final filePath = "pdf viewer/pdf viewer/bin/Release/filePath.txt";
  final file = File(filePath);
  file.writeAsStringSync(path);
} catch (r) {}

final pdfViewerPath = "pdf viewer/pdf viewer/bin/Release/pdf viewer.exe";
final file2 = File(pdfViewerPath);
print(file2.absolute.path);
ProcessResult result = await Process.run(
  file2.absolute.path,
  ['--WindowStyle', 'Maximized'],
  runInShell: true,
);
print(result.exitCode);
```

}

Comment: Friends, I solved the problem, when I build the project, the file paths change, so the exe file takes the folder it is working in, I updated the file paths and it worked.